# Initializing (Entity) object by calling (get) property dynamically. Entity Framework , c#, ASP>NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dynamic, linq-to-entities

I have below piece of code:

```cs
public void DBMamLookup(int custid)
{
    using (LookUpEntities1 lookUp = new LookUpEntities1())
    {
        
        var mamconfig = lookUp.MamConfigurations;
        var userlookup = lookUp.UserAccount2_ISO2_3 ;
        
        MamConfiguration obj = mamconfig.Where(m => m.CustID== custid).FirstOrDefault();
        var objNN = lookUp.UserAccount2_ISO2_3.Where(m => m.CustID== custid).Take(15).ToList();            
        
        Type returnType;
        switch (obj.ActiveTableName)
        {
            case "MamConfiguration":
                returnType = typeof(MamConfiguration);
                break;                                            
            case "UserAccount1_ISO1_1Billers":                        
                returnType = typeof(UserAccount1_ISO2_3Billers);
                break;                    
            default:
                returnType = typeof(UserAccount2_ISO2_3Billers);
                break;
        }
        dynamic que3 = this.GetInstance<dynamic>(obj.ActiveTableName);                
        que3 = lookUp.Set(returnType);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < que3.Local.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(que3.Local[i].UserAccount);
        }       
    }
}
```

I have problem at below line in above code:

```cs
var objNN = lookUp.**UserAccount2_ISO2_3**.Where(m => m.CustID== custid).Take(15).ToList();
```

I have to make it dynamic and call the specific entity property at runtime. As I have property name in string i.e. obj.ActiveTableName how can I make a call something like below:

```cs
var objNN = lookUp.**[obj.ActiveTableName]**.Where(m => m.CustID== custid).Take(15).ToList();
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Such requirement comes into project where I have lots of entity tables and entity properties return data into type of those table and table have their separate properties like custid, custname etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an interface with common properties for all types:
For example:

```
interface IEntityWithCustID
{
    int CustID { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure all relevant classes implement that interface
For example:

```
public class UserAccount2_ISO2_3 : IEntityWithCustID
```

Create a helper class to retrieve data

```
static class QueryHelper
{
    public static List<IEntityWithCustID> GetResult(LookUpEntities1 lookup, string tableName, int custId)
    {
        var dbset = lookup.GetType().GetProperty(tableName).GetValue(lookup);
        var entityType = dbset.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var method = typeof(QueryHelper).GetMethod(nameof(GetResultInternal)).MakeGenericMethod(entityType);
        return (List<IEntityWithCustID>)method.Invoke(null, new object[] { dbset, custId });
    }

    public static List<IEntityWithCustID> GetResultInternal<T>(IDbSet<T> dbset, int custId) where T: class, IEntityWithCustID
    {
        return dbset.Where(m => m.CustID == custId).Take(15).ToList().Cast<IEntityWithCustID>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Use that class from your code (For example)

```
var res = QueryHelper.GetResult(lookup, obj.ActiveTableName, custid);
```

There is another way where you can create Expression.Lambda to create custom lambda expression using Expression.Lambda call. It will be a little bit more complicated though.

Comment: Just a note about my suggested solution, while it "works", there are better way to solve this. One way is make all entities that share common properties, share a common table using Table Per Hierarchy, and filter by type. Or may be there are better ways even depending on your problem.